# Can't display image uploaded in JSP page but it shows when the url is typed in the browser's address bar

Tags: image, jsp, servlets, browser, upload

My web Java project with servlets/jsp can upload images (even thought is not the best way), but when I try to show the images in a table (using JSTL), there's just a blank image, like the url of image is broken. But when I copy the url image and paste in the browser's address bar, the image is shown as expected. The url is like this:

```
file:///c:/Users/user/Documents/NetBeansProjects/Project1/target/Project-1.0-SNAPSHOT//images/image1.png
```

This is how is set on the JSP page:

```
<img src="<c:out value="${requestScope.path}" /><c:out value="${test.image}" />" />
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Please don't vandalize your posts. By posting on the Stack Exchange network, you've granted a non-revocable right, under the [CC BY-SA 4.0](https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/4.0/) license, for Stack Exchange to distribute that content (i.e. regardless of your future choices). By Stack Exchange policy, the non-vandalized version of the post is the one which is distributed, and thus, any vandalism will be reverted. If you want to know more about deleting a post please see: [How does deleting work?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/what-to-do-instead-of-deleting-question).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you type a URL with a file protocol into your browser's address bar, your browser asks your operating system for the file. When you put that same URL into a img tag on a HTML page, the browser now makes a HTTP request for the file. But, the file is not accessible over the internet. In order to do what want to do, you must have a Servlet read the file from the file system and then put it into a HTTP response that can be sent when the browser requests the image. Here is demonstration code.

```
package rick;
import java.io.IOException;
import jakarta.servlet.ServletException;
import jakarta.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;
import jakarta.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import jakarta.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import jakarta.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
@WebServlet("/serveImage")
public class ServeImage extends HttpServlet {
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        response.setContentType("image/jpeg");
        FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream("C:/Users/rick/Documents/RickProfile.jpeg");
        fis.transferTo(response.getOutputStream());
    }
}
```

and request it with an img tag like

```
  <img src="serveImage" />
```